# Google Wallet Online Commerce API : Unable to receive the Masked Wallet Response

Tags: gwt, google-api, android-pay

I had a few questions regarding the Google Wallet Online Commerce API.

1. I understand that the API are available for use by a selective merchants approved by Google. Is it the case for using the sandbox environment as well?

2a. How do we get the seller id and seller secret for Online Commerce API? 
2b. Is the Seller Id and seller secret same as the merchant ID and merchant key available on registering on the sandbox environment for Seller?
2c. I could get the details for Seller ID and Seller Secret for Wallet APIs for Digital Goods - Can the same be used for Online Commerce APIs as well?

1. We tried to do a POC on Google Wallet Integration , We are able to successfully use the createWalletButton API. On clicking the button , I am asked to login to Google Wallets - which is successful as well. But the call to retreive the wallet information fails. The following error is displayed:

Uh-Oh. There was a problem.
Sorry, Google Wallet couldn’t complete your request. Please return to the merchant to choose a different payment method, or try again later.
Error: 62 (121217125033+0530)

The same error is also seen when trying to call the requestMaskedWallet API. Please advise.

A prompt response will be helpful and much appreciated.

Thanks,
Neha